# regex in vimscript

Tags: regex, vim, viml

```
let test = 'a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a;'
```

In vimscript, how can I get `http://www.google.com` out of this using a regexp, and store it in another variable?

I can't seem to find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
let url = matchstr(test, '\ca href=\([''"]\)\zs.\{-}\ze\1')
if empty(url) 
   throw "no url recognized into ``".test."''"
endif
```

For more information, see:

```
:h matchstr()
:h /\c
:h /\zs
:h /\{-
```

Comment: thanks! will look those up. i just don't know where to search for when it comes to vimscript

Comment: @guest: Worst case, you can skim through `:help functions` (alphabetical) or `:help function-list` (by category) to find functions.