# How to use regular expressions on variables with text in vimscript?

Tags: regex, vim

I have text saved in a variable, for example, like this:

```
let text = getline(line(".")-1)
```

How do I check if the text matches a regular expression? I'm expecting something like this:

```
let text = getline(line(".")-1)
if regexp_match(text, "^[Ss]tuff$")
    dostuff
endif
```

Comment: Well... Tried typing :h regex and pressing tab attempting to find something in help that could, well, help. Are you sure that "what have you tried?" is an appropriate question when someone asks for a way to do something?

Comment: Well, a quick google search of "vim-script regex" returns as it's top result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135322/regex-in-vimscript . It would help if you do some legwork before asking a question.

Comment: YMMV with legwork depending on the paths you take. I came here with a Google search of `vimscript if regex` first, so thanks for providing this link.  Better still, the own research you encouraged the OP to do provides the actual answer that they and I were looking for, which your link does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Made some more research and found out that what I needed is [=~# operator](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-%3D%7E%23) which is used to check if some text matches a regexp:

```
if "text"=~#"^te.."
    echo "Matches!"
```

Comment: Sometimes it's better to use single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"` around your regex.  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28233/why-doesnt-regex-work-in-vimscript-while-it-does-in-normal-search