# Return substring match vimscript

Tags: vim

I want to extract the url of a markdown link using vimscript with regexes.

Ideally something in these lines:

```
fun! GetLinkUri(str)
    return match(a:str, '[.*]\((.*)\)', \1)
endfunc
```

So given a string like: `The search engine [Google](https://google.com) blabla`
It would return `https://google.com`.

The way the function is described is not the proper use of match. There's any way of doing it with match? There are any other function that does this job?

Comment: see `:h matchstr`, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135322/regex-in-vimscript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are going to need to use `matchstr` instead of `match`. But that's not the only problem you have. I would do this:

```
return matchstr(a:str, '\[.*\](\zs.*\ze)')
```

1. `[.*]` means match *one* character, that is either a `'.'` or a `'*'`. You need to escape the square brackets if you would like to match literal square brackets.
2. Unfortunately, `matchstr` can't return an individual subgroup, so I used `\zs` and `\ze` to restrict the matching section to what's between the parentheses.